# Why do http-bio-80 threads keep open after sending their data (Tomcat)?

Tags: tomcat, timeout, keep-alive

In my Apache Tomcat manager in the server status are a lot (>100) of the following threads:

```
Stage Time      B Sent B Recv Client         VHost        Request
S     355655 ms 16 KB  0KB    xxx.xxx.xx.xxx mydomain.com GET /audiofiles/file2908.mp3
S     627626 ms 40 KB  0KB    xxx.xxx.xx.xxx mydomain.com GET /audiofiles/file2913.mp3
S       6685 ms 40 KB  0KB    xxx.xxx.xx.xxx mydomain.com GET /audiofiles/file2924.mp3
S     229365 ms 16 KB  0KB    xxx.xxx.xx.xxx mydomain.com GET /audiofiles/file2921.mp3
S     729470 ms 16 KB  0KB    xxx.xxx.xx.xxx mydomain.com GET /audiofiles/file2916.mp3
```

It seems these requests were succesfully sent, but somebody (server or client) failed to close the connection. These threads stack up pretty high and I'm worried it might affect performance of the server. I have read about `maxKeepAliveRequests` in the [Connector-documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html), and maybe this is the cause. However, this value defaults to 100 and there are way over the 100 threads hanging like this (currently ~150). Should I worry? Or will Tomcat automatically close these threads when it needs the memory?

I can imagine keeping connections alive may be effective for short periods, but why is there no timeout on it? Why would anybody want this feature for way over 500 seconds, I think those clients may have already left the webpage (especially the one on which the mp3 file can be played).

Are there any other settings in Tomcat that I may have missed in the documentation, for example, to set the maximum timeout between packets sent in the connection? The only timeouts I've come across are hard, thus close the connection after a specific time even though the client is for example actually downloading a large file which just takes some time.

Somehow this problem started to occur when I started using audiofiles, none of my servlets or downloaded javascript-files or anything else are causing any hanging. Any help is very much appreciated!